# Meaning of "pain", "bœuf" and "clou" in music?

Tags: expressions-idiomatiques

French musicians use the following expressions :

- *Amener son clou*
- *Faire un bœuf*
- *Mettre des pains*

What do they means and what is their origin?

An example of "clou" :

[image]

Comment: Asking for an English translation is off topic here. Do you look for the meaning or the origin of these expressions?

Comment: @Lambie Maybe because at least two of them are used by musicians.

Comment: @Lambie because I know they use these expressions !

Comment: @jiliagre I tihnk I rouhgly understand the meaning, I'm interessted in origin (though I think that Boeuf come from 'Boeuf sur le toit") and (sorry for that if it's of-topic) equivalent in english ..

Comment: It would useful to have examples of these expressions in actual texts in French.

Comment: Je pense que lá, clou veut dire: instrument.

Comment: @Lambie : exact ! And it seems to be a kind of piece of french musical "slang" .. but where does it come from ? (and, again off-topic, is there any equivalent in english ?) ..

Comment: Ok, so look here: https://jipiblog.jipiz.fr/2017/02/22/largot-des-musicos/ Mettre un instrument au clou: le porter dans un mont de piété pour récupérer un peu de monnaie. So, ***maybe*** it derives from that since many musicians are forced to pawn their instruments at some point. So clou came to mean instrument. **I am just guessing here**.

Answer (score 5):

- 1. ***Amener son clou***
     [image]

I had never heard that expression before. ***Clou*** is used here to simply name a random musical instrument, some "metallic tool" or just "musical tool". It might be connected to ***boite à clous***, slang for "toolbox". I found it in a couple of other jazz related FB pages:

[Skookianbrassband](https://www.facebook.com/photo/?fbid=335433265253760&set=a.127034462760309):

> *Le stage est ouvert aux instrumentistes à vent et aux percussionnistes à partir de 10 ans. Pas besoin d'être un virtuose ni de savoir lire la musique, **il faut juste être un minimum autonome avec son clou***

[Nicolas Gardel](https://www.facebook.com/watch/?v=903573747220539):

> Qu’est ce qu’un musicien fait en rentrant de tournée !? **Il bosse son clou non de non**

and here is a forum where *clou* is used to name a violin ([Lutin Malin](https://www.le-violon.org/viewtopic.php?t=4456#p74179)):

> — ... J'ai seulement peur que ça se transforme en tendinite ou un truc du style et que je ne puisse plus toucher mon violon pendant 3 semaines :(
> — Ca m'est arrivé. **Je n'ai pas pu toucher à mon clou pendant un mois**.
> Et c'est progressivement que j'ai pu m'y remettre, en jouant .... 5 minutes par jour

The word *clou* is used to name the *chevilles* used to keep the strings in place on a guitar or a violin. That might be an explanation for the origin of the word.

- 2. *[**Faire un bœuf**](https://www.midi-madagasikara.mg/2016/09/08/musique-faire-boeuf-dou-vient-cette-expression/)* [image]

This is a common expression. That means musicians from different origin gather together and improvise. All sources tell it comes from the cabaret named [*Le **bœuf** sur le toit*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Le_B%C5%93uf_sur_le_toit_(cabaret)): *In France, the expression "faire un bœuf" is used by musicians to this day to mean "to have a jam session" and derives from the name of this cabaret.*

- 3. ***Mettre des pains*** [image]

This expression has a general meaning in French slang (to punch, to hit people) but in the context of musicians, it means to play false notes. Here is [a blog talking about these ***pains***](http://atelierdechantchoral.blogspot.com/2008/01/au-temps-pour-moi.html):

> *Aujourd'hui, je commence avec "les pains" qui en musique signifient les fausses ou mauvaises (ce qui n'est pas tout à fait pareil) notes. On dit "mettre des pains" (faire des fausses notes) et par extension : "la boulangerie est ouverte". On parle aussi de "la multiplication des (petits) pains" qui est tout sauf un miracle pour les oreilles du chef !*

Several sources tell that this expression comes from music academies and orchestras where the one who made a mistake (wrong or off-beat note) had to offer the meal (the bread: ***le pain***) to the rest of the band.

Comment: https://jipiblog.jipiz.fr/2017/02/22/largot-des-musicos/Faire le bœuf  : expression très connue. Réunion de musiciens qui jouent entre eux pour la plaisir. On dit aussi  : faire une jam. (jam session) a complete glossary. [in every other forum, OPs are asked to provide background or examples etc. I guess here on this forum no one cares about tha t.]

Comment: Also, this: Mettre un instrument au clou: le porter dans un mont de piété pour récupérer un peu de monnaie. Charlie Parker le faisait souvent. To pawn an instrument. Dunno about amener though.

Comment: @Lambie Your *clou* is absolutely unrelated to the OP one (assuming the expression is really *amener son clou*), gross misunderstanding here. Stack Exchange site are **not** forums. If you are unhappy with questions and answers, use the Meta site to express your feelings but don't pollute other people contributions.

Comment: I **know that amener son clou is not what is in that glossary**. Why do you suppose I said: Dunno about amener? Do I have to repeat the entire idea for you like this: I do not know about amener son clou.

Comment: I posted that comment in square brackets as an aside. Does HRH allow those? Or not?

Comment: Arrête de poster pour ne rien dire. J'ai flagué tes commentaires inutiles et agressifs.

Comment: There is nothing aggressive about my comment. And I gave you the glossary so you can include it in your answer. If I had posted it above under the question, you would have told me to enter an answer. You do have a high-handed attitude with me here. Even when I try to help, you seem to find a way to denigrate what I say.

Comment: There is something agressive or "disgruntled" in most of the comments you make. What you wrote about *le bœuf* was already stated in my reply. *Faire le jam* / *faire un jam*  are much rarer that *faire un bœuf*, at least in France. If you feel that expression deserve to be present in an answer, post you own and please stop commenting every reply of mine.

Comment: Le _clou_ est curieux. Si c'est dans le sens d'amener pour une représentation, ça pourrait être comme dans _biclou_, la vieille affaire... instrument, ou ça pourrait être l'[_outil_](https://archive.org/details/dictionnairedela00delvuoft/page/92/mode/2up), et j'ai noté aussi il _joue comme un_ [clou](https://archive.org/details/dictionnaireargo00deleuoft/page/70/mode/2up), peut-être même au figuré le même _clou_ que celui du spectacle ?

Comment: @Earendelle ou peut-être celui qui permet de clouer le bec ;-)

Comment: I was **agreeing and showing that it is in a glossary**. What's wrong with providing you with information you can use in your answer? What I posted was a **dictionary entry**, not something I wrote.  If you click on the link, you will see that that is how it is written there.... This link works: https://jipiblog.jipiz.fr/2017/02/22/largot-des-musicos/ The other one does not. See how **they say it**. It was not me saying it.

Comment: @Lambie When you quote sources, use proper typography to make clear who wrote what, pay attention to the links (the one you posted is broken) and prefer error-free sources (I thought it was yours because of the gender mismatch).

Comment: Ramène ton cl;ou et ton envie de jouer: clou=instrument //So, it could be a synecdoche of some kind. Who knows, I do not. Please stop giving me instructions. I just mis-posted the link, it happens. And if you bothered to **really think about it**, how likely am I to say: faire le boeuf: expression très connue, when I obviously posted a glossary.

Comment: "Your clou is absolutely unrelated to the OP one (assuming the expression is really amener son clou), gross misunderstanding here." Maybe not.  Perhaps you are too quick to react.

Comment: @Lambie The *Mont-de-Piété* thing can't be used with *ramener ton*. That's simply impossible. You didn't "just misposted the link", there was no evidence the text wasn't yours, nothing obvious.

Comment: The entry in that glossary is this: **"Mettre un instrument au clou: le porter dans un mont de piété pour récupérer un peu de monnaie. Charlie Parker le faisait souvent"**.  **It is possible that clou has come to be identified with an instrument** due to this expression. If clou is instrument, which the OP says it is, then in any case:  Ramène ton clou et ton envie de jouer means: Bring your instrument and your desire to play. Like I said, you react too fast. [I did just mis-post the link. And I copied the dictionary entry, which **you misread** due to that.]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135230/discussion-between-jlliagre-and-lambie).

Comment: @jiliagre thank's for your answer .. your hypothesis for 'clou''s origin has sense